# How to split a face in Surface_mesh

Tags: mesh, cgal

I am using the `CGAL::Surface_mesh` class to represent a 3d triangle mesh. I wanted to use this instead of the `Polyhedral_3` mesh due to its simplicity and index structure and ease of use with OpenGL. I am trying to write a method to perform 1-4 subdivision of a triangle and cannot find how to do so in the documentation. Is there a way to split faces (1-4 splitting or barycentric splitting) in a `Surface_mesh` class similar to the `create_center_vertex` in `Polyhedral_3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a set of generic functions that are working both on Surface_mesh, Polyhedron and even OpenMesh. In the BGL package, see the [Euler operations](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/group__PkgBGLEulerOperations.html).
The one you are looking for is [here](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/group__PkgBGLEulerOperations.html#ga28e4d0f61f3cda26eb651e352cf756ce).

Comment: Oh wow, that should have been more obvious in retrospect. I find the CGAL documentation to be, while expansive, very difficult to navigate at first.  Thanks very much for the pointer!

Comment: It is also probably useful to note that the `create_center_vertex` function does NOT set the position of the new center vertex. This is mentioned in the docs but is easy to miss.